# Optimizing aggregation query against wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I am running an aggregation query against wiki data. The query tries to calculate the average duration of films, grouped by their genre and the year of publication

The multiple grouping/subqueries in the query are intended to retain an `n-1` relationship from film to the grouping criteria (year and genre) and a `1-1` relationship between a film and its duration. Reason for this is having approximately correct aggregations (n-1 relationships are familiar for OLAP and data warehousing practitioners).

More explanation is embedded in the query. Hence I cannot drop down the groupings done in the subqueries and the if statements or the group concatenation. This query times out on [Wikidata SPARQL endpoint](https://query.wikidata.org).

**QUESTION**

I need some suggestion for performance enhancement... ***Any optimization hints***? In case that's not possible, anyone aware of some ***authenticated way*** (so that they know I am not playing around) to query Wikidata so that timeout can be increased, or a way to ***increase timeout generally***?

```
    # Average duration of films, grouped by their genre and the year of publication       
SELECT  
        ?genre1                    # film genre
        ?year1                     # film year of publication
        (AVG(?duration1) AS ?avg)   # film average duration

WHERE
        {      
            # Calculating the average duration for each single film.
            # As there are films with multiple duration, these durations are 
            # averagred by grouping aggregating durations by film.
            # Hence, a single duration for each film is projected out from the subquery.
            {
              select ?film (avg(?duration) as ?duration1)  
              where{
                ?film   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P2047>   ?duration .    
              }group by ?film
            }

            # Here the grouping criteria (genre and year) are calculated.
            # The criteria is grouped by film, so that in case multiple 
            # genre/multiple year exist for a single film, all of them are
            # group concated into a single value.
            # Also in case of a lack of a value of year or genre for some
            # specific film, a dummy value "OtherYear"/"OtherGenre" is generated.
            {
              select ?film (
                                IF
                                (
                                    group_concat(distinct ?year ; separator="-- ") != "", 
                                    # In case multiple year exist for a single film, all of them are group concated into a single value.
                                    group_concat(distinct ?year ; separator="-- "), 
                                   # In case of a lack of a value of year for some specific film, a dummy value "OtherYear" is generated.
                                    "OtherYear"                                        
                                )
                                as ?year1
                              )
                                (
                                IF
                                (
                                    group_concat(distinct ?genre ; separator="-- ") != "",
                                    # In case multiple genre exist for a single film, all of them are group concated into a single value.
                                    group_concat(distinct ?genre ; separator="-- "), 
                                    # In case of a lack of a value of genre for some specific film, a dummy value "OtherGenre" is generated.
                                    "OtherGenre"  
                                )
                                as ?genre1
                              ) 

              where 
              {
                ?film  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31>  <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q11424> .
                 optional {
                   ?film   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P577>  ?date .
                   BIND(year(?date) AS ?year)
                 }
                 optional {
                   ?film <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P136>  ?genre .
                 }
              } group by ?film              
          }

        } GROUP BY ?year1 ?genre1
```

Comment: it's basically your second subquery that already leads to a timeout.

Comment: I'm not aware of any account to increase the timeout for a user, I mean it's not a payed service. Indeed, you can always just download the dataset and use your own local triple store. The dataset itself is free

Comment: I just found a logical bug in your query. There are `166177` films not having a duration at all. That will lead to a much small result in the end when you're not using an `OPTIONAL` pattern for the duration as will, given that both subqueries will be joined on the `?film` variable

Comment: @AKSW it is the intended behaviour. There is no point in including films with no duration when calculating average duration.

Comment: @AKSW  However, this could be a good hint. Now I am not quite sure whether all films are inspected in the second subquery. If so, maybe I can rule out a magnificent fraction of the data using the first subquery -including only films that have duration in the second subquery-.

Comment: that's what I'm trying right now :D - but still a timeout so far

Answer (score 1):

The query seems to work after replacing the two `IF` expressions with a simple `sample` (which picks an arbitrary value from the group):

```
    (sample(?year) as ?year1)
    (sample(?genre) as ?genre1)
```

So it appears that the expense of `group_concat` is the main problem. I don't find that very intuitive and have no explanation.

Maybe the version with `sample` is good enough, or at least it may give you a baseline point for further improvements.

Comment: I just took the second subquery and it leads to a timeout with `group_concat`. Not sure how `sample` is generated, but maybe it doesn't fetch all values first but just uses the first occurrence, thus, is faster?

Comment: SAMPLE returns an arbitrary non-empty subset of the values. There is no indication how these values are selected or what is there count, as far as I can tell.

Comment: For your interest, I downloaded the relevant subset of the data via `CONSTRUCT` query and then use good old Apache Jena CLI which returns the result in ~11s.

Comment: @cygri, thanks for the hint... I will try a couple of workarounds... Let's see what I get. But frankly group_concat is kinda required... I am aiming at some other mechanisms... Ordering of the triple patterns, some alternative for optional (which is obviously costs as well), or organizations of subqueries...

Comment: @AKSW YES... on my local graphdb the query takes ~4 seconds to complete... But it would be great to have it run on the wikidata endpoint... Kind of a requirement...

Comment: @MedianHilal I see. But it's even your second subquery alone that leads to a timeout. And given that you have only two left-joins which have to completed before the aggregation, I don't see any possible optimizations.

Comment: @AKSW Yes probably it just picks the first value. Not tested but I would assume sample returns the first part of the concatenation that is returned by group_concat.